# How do I access resource files in a php class

Tags: php, mysql, json, file-get-contents

I have a class named CMS which relies on a file names "DB.json"

I am using the following code:

```
class CMS{
  function __construct(){
    $DB = json_decode(file_get_contents("DB.json"));
  }
}
```

which works fine as long as the file I am requiring the class from is inside the same directory

so if "/classes/cms/lib.php" is my class file and require "lib.php" inside the file "/classes/cms/form.php" then it will work

but if I require "/classes/cms/lib.php" from inside of a file such as "/home.php" then I get an error message saying that the file "DB.json" doesn't exist

link: http://www.streamlinedesign.ml/testcms.php

Comment: You're confusing URLs with file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use magic constant `__DIR__` - it will indicate the directory of the current file (from which the constant is accessed):

```
class CMS{
  function __construct(){
    $DB = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."DB.json"));
  }
}
```